# How to show images and text using react-native-material-dropdown?

Tags: react-native

I'm developing social app using react-native.
There, I have one problm during developing.
I used react-native-material-dropdown module for making dropdown.
I want to show images and text on each element on dropdown.
But react-native-material-dropdown module doesn't support this feature.
How can I solve this problem?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the renderBase prop, see [this](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown/issues/133) and [this](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown/issues/134) issues that could help you :)